# System.NotSupportedException: A collection's thread ownership seems changed at runtime

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a UpFile class to monitor file change at specific application directory:

```
class UpFile
{
    public string file { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int long1 { get; set; }
    public int short1 { get; set; }
    static public System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<UpFile> _upfiles =
        new System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<UpFile>();
}
```

and FileWatcher :

```
class FileWatcher
{
    public void Start(Callback callback)
    {
        _callback = callback;
        _watcher.Path = Config._upDirectory;
        _watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite;
        _watcher.Filter = "*.up";
        _watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = false;
        _watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnNewFile);
        _watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChangeFile);
        _watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        _started = true;
    }
    private void OnChangeFile(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs args)
    {
        Logger.I("OnChangeFile " + args.FullPath);
        CheckFile(args.FullPath);
    }
    private void CheckFile(string fileName)
    {
            Logger.I("New UpFile:" + mbplcflow);
            UpFile newFile = new UpFile { id = mbplcflow, file = fileName, long1 = long1, short1 = short1 };
            UpFile._upfiles.Add(newFile);
            _callback();
    }
}
```

And the delegate is on UI thread to show all changed items in DataGrid control, it is in the MainWindow class:

```
    private void UpFileCreated()
    {
        if (Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
            dgUp.ItemsSource = UpFile._upfiles;
        else
            Dispatcher.Invoke(delegate { dgUp.ItemsSource = UpFile._upfiles; });
    }
```

The first file change runs perfectly, I see file change item is added to the UI DataGrid control. But when the second file change comes, I got "System.NotSupportedException" at the line:

```
UpFile._upfiles.Add(newFile);
```

So I don't understand why the _upfiles's thread ownership is changed over time? How can I make it not owned by the UI thread?

BTW this is the log I got:

```
I 16:47:48.169 OnChangeFile c:\test\test\23732_1657874868168.up
I 16:47:48.175 New UpFile:19
```

But when second file change comes it stopped at the exception.

Comment: Did you plan to add the "WPF" tag? "wfp" is something completely different

Comment: What's the Message and call stack of the exception?

Comment: @KlausGütter that's a mistake

Comment: It is not lying to you, that's what assigning the ItemsSource property did.  Get ahead by giving the callback an UpFile parameter so you can leave updating the UI completely to the UI thread. Also helps you get rid of that very ugly static variable.